# Get fastlane to print test case errors on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, fastlane

In a simple project when running the unit tests lane locally on my system, fastlane does not report any error despite the test case having a failing test method such as this:

```
import XCTest
@testable import CICDDemo

final class CICDDemoTests: XCTestCase {

    func testFailure() {
        XCTAssertTrue(1==2)
    }
}
```

I have my fastfile setup like this, following which I run `fastlane unit_tests` in Terminal

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Description of what the lane does"
  lane :custom_lane do
    # add actions here: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions
  end

  # Unit tests lane
  lane :unit_tests do
    run_tests(build_for_testing: true,
              scheme: "CICDDemo",
              only_testing: "CICDDemo",
              device: "iPhone 14")
  end
end
```

The fastlane output shows this:

```
[11:28:07]: ▸ Processing empty-CICDDemo.plist
[11:28:08]: ▸ Linking CICDDemo
[11:28:10]: ▸ Processing empty-CICDDemoTests.plist
[11:28:10]: ▸ Linking CICDDemoTests
[11:28:11]: ▸ Processing empty-CICDDemoUITests.plist
[11:28:12]: ▸ Linking CICDDemoUITests
[11:28:12]: ▸ Test build Succeeded

+---------------------------------------+
|           fastlane summary            |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action           | Time (in s) |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform | 0           |
| 2    | run_tests        | 31          |
+------+------------------+-------------+

[11:28:13]: fastlane.tools finished successfully
```

My goal is to get fastlane to print the filename(s) and method(s) being tested as well as the success or error if any. Do I need to use [scan](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/run_tests/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles onto this, the issue was the config setting `build_for_testing`. According to the [documentation](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/run_tests/),
[image]

Removing it fixed the issue.